# Точки по центру текста

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка

Как сделать адаптивным такой блок с текстом и точками?:

текст1.....................................................................123
большой текст................................................................1234
ещё текст...................................................................123

т.е. точки по центру должны регулироваться в зависимости от размера экрана, уменьшаться на меленьких размерах экрана.
Текст находится в тегах li.
Может быть сам текст обернуть в теги span.left и цифры в span.right а точки сделать с помощью after?

Comment: http://shop.bearmade.ru/shop/parket/lesnaya-tropa-2/
Посмотри как здесь делал блок с размерами.